# Select from a list using another list of limits

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list of values

```
list1 = {2.4, 3.4, 5.9, 1.2, 9.5, 7.5}
```

and a another list containing theoretical maximum values

```
list2 = {3, 4, 6, 2, 9, 7}
```

I wish to select those values from `list1` which are less than the corresponding maximum value. So from my example I would get the values

> ```
> {2.4, 3.4, 5.9, 1.2}
> ```

Something like this (which doesn't work)

```
Select[list1, # < list2] &
```

Comment: `Pick[list1, Thread[Less[list1, list2]]]`...

Comment: @ciao ); I was about to post exactly  the same !!!

Comment: @SquareOne: That's probably the canonical way, and `Pick[list1, UnitStep[Subtract[list1, list2]], 0]` if speed matters for huge lists...

Comment: Thank you ciao.  I didn't know Pick existed.

Comment: @StevenAnderson No worries. Also, your result example is missing last value, and the `Select` is non-working (it's missing the `&` on the test to make it a function).

Comment: @ciao Why your second form is faster ? You should post your answers

Comment: @SquareOne: Ah, these are really not "answer" material IMO, feel free to if you'd like. Second is faster for a couple of reasons: most times if you can do things arithmetically, you gain speed (intrinsic speed of simple math ops in MMA, under-the-covers parallelization/divide-n-conquer/etc.), and some operations (like `Pick`) use optimized strategies when they "know" things about the data structures - like a target has been `Unitized` or `UnitSteped` - so second form can be orders of magnitude faster on large lists - try it!

Comment: @ciao Perchance, do you how the usual `Pick[ x, f[x,list]]` get advantage of parallelism?

Comment: @belisarius: Conjecture on my part re: `Pick`, seeing as other more complex ops are auto-parallelized, it's inconceivable that a `Pick` operation would not be segmented when possible. But again, conjecture re: `Pick`, I've never tested use cases of it to verify, nor disassembled (verboten by license)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ciao's method is good.

```
Pick[list1, Thread[Less[list1, list2]]]
```

> ```
> {2.4, 3.4, 5.9, 1.2}
> ```

Another -- perhaps more direct -- way to do it is

```
MapThread[If[#1 <= #2, #1, Nothing] &, {list1, list2}]
```

> ```
> {2.4, 3.4, 5.9, 1.2}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[Transpose[{list1, list2}], {a_, b_} /; a < b :> a]
```

> {2.4, 3.4, 5.9, 1.2}

Comment: what does the a <b:>a do in your logic?  I see that it works I just don't understand how.